# Reference request and clarification for Central Limit Theorem for complex random variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, limits-and-convergence

I'm looking for a reference and a proof of the following version (or eventually a more general version) of the Central Limit Theorem for complex random variables.

**Theorem.** *Let $Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n$ be independent identically distributed complex Goodman (see Note 1) random variables with mean $\mu$ and complex variance $\sigma^2$ (see Note 2). Then as $n \to \infty$
$$(\star)\quad\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i - \mu n}{(\sigma^2 n)^{1/2}}$$
converges in law to a standard complex normal random variable.*

**Note 1.** A complex random variable $Z = X + iY$ ($X, Y \in \mathbb{R}$) is *Goodman* if the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is zero.

**Note 2.** The complex variance of a complex random variable $Z$ is defined as $\mathbf{E}\left[(Z - \mathbf{E}[Z])\overline{(Z - \mathbf{E}[Z])}\right]$.

The only references I was able to find are:

1. Theorem 7.3, Jonathan Shuster, Properties of the Gaussian Gaussian Distribution (this is an apparently unpublished B.Sc. thesis).
2. Exercise 2.2.14, Terrence Tao, Topics in Random Matrix Theory (this is an exercise without solution).

I would like a published reference, possibly a book, containing a proof.
In general, I'm a bit surprise of not finding books devoted to complex random variables. Perhaps this is due to the fact that many theorems on complex random variables follow easily from theorems on real random variables.

Furthermore, I don't understand why the condition on begin Goodman is needed ((1) provides a counter-example but I don't find it enlightening). Since ($\star$) involves only additive properties on the complex random variables, why one cannot deduce the Central Limit Theorem for complex random variables just be identifying $Z$ with the real vector $(X, Y)$ and using the Central Limit Theorem for vectors?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you mean "Properties of the *Inverse* Gaussian Distribution"?

Comment: And forgive me for asking a stupid question, but when you write the "complex variance $\sigma^2$", we're talking about the real-valued variance of a complex variable, right?

Comment: @BillBradley I don't understand what to you mean by "properties of the inverse Gaussian distribution." I added a note with the definition of complex variance.

Comment: I don't see a problem to apply the CLT for i.i.d. sequences of $\mathbb R^d$-valued $L_2$-random vectors $X_n$. Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (X_k-E(X_k))$ converges weakly to $N(0,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of $X_1$.

Comment: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~stindel/teaching/ma539/clt.pdf

Comment: @JochenWengenroth that's my impression too. But then why Shuster and Tao add the hypothesis of being Goodman variables? (Tao doesn't use the term "Goodman" but explicitly says that the covariance of the real and immaginary part is zero)

Comment: @rosan98, re: "inverse Gaussian": I mean you appear to have mistyped the reference in your post; you wrote "Gaussian Gaussian".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the "Furthermore":

The central limit theorem for vectors involves the variance-covariance matrix. Let $Z = X+iY$ be a complex random variable (with mean $0$ for simplicity). If $X,Y$ have variance-covariance matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf E[X^2] & \mathbf E[XY] \\ \mathbf E[XY] & \mathbf E [Y^2] \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix} $$

then the complex variance is $$\mathbb E [ (X+iY) (X- i Y) ]= \mathbb E[ X^2+Y^2] =a+c$$ so knowing the complex variance does not determine the variance-covariance matrix and thus doesn't determine the limiting distribution.

Your definition of Goodman  is equivalent to $b=0$. Even under $b=0$ knowing $a+c$ does not determine the full matrix. The reference by Shuster gives a different definition of Goodman, which is equivalent to $b=0$ and $a=c$. It is clear from the matrix perspective why such an assumption is necessary (since every symmetric positive semidefinite matrix can in fact appear). (The reference by Tao doesn't use the notion of Goodman random variables, but has a similar assumption.)

Comment: Ah... so the "Goodman" assumption is needed not because without it we cannot prove the convergence in law, but because without it we cannot say to "which" distribution we have convergence in law, since we cannot determine the variance-covariance matrix... Am I understanding it right? Thanks

Comment: @rosan98 That is my understanding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Will's answer: The $b=[EY]=0$ condition can be dropped if one is allowed to take the normalizing $1/\sigma$ to be complex. For any candidate normalization $1/\sigma$, write it in polar coordinate as $1/\sigma= \rho e^{i\theta}$. Multiplication of $Z_i$ by the complex $1/\sigma$ is equivalent to multiplication of $(X_i,Y_i)^T$ by the matrix
$$
M = \rho \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that the complex $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt n}\sum_i Z_i$ is written in $\mathbb R^2$ as the vector $n^{-1/2} M\sum_i (X_i,Y_i)^T$, which by the CLT for random vectors in $R^2$ has normal limiting distribution with covariance
$$M \begin{pmatrix} EX^2 & E[XY] \\ E[XY] & E[Y^2]\end{pmatrix}M^T.$$
So the only changes that can be achieved through normalizating by $\sigma$ are:

- A rotation by $\theta$ of the two eigenvectors (the rotation does not affect the eigenvalues), for instance we could normalize by a rotation that makes the real and imaginary parts independent in the covariance matrix, which allows to drop the condition $E[XY]=0$.
- Multiplication by $\rho^2$ of the eigenvalues (which does not affect the eigenvectors).

In any case the two real eigenvalues can only by multiplied by the same $\rho$, so the ratio between eigenvalues of the limiting covariance matrix is unchanged by normalization by any complex $1/\sigma$. It is not possible to reach a limiting complex standard normal distribution through normalization by $1/\sigma$ unless the two eigenvalues of the covariance are equal in the first place.